# Geometry, quadrilateral and parallelogram

Tags: geometry

Parallelogram $MNPQ$ with diagonals $QN $and $MP$,  $MR=5 (a+7)$ and $MP=12a+34$, find $MR$, $RP$, and $MP$. How can I solve this? I set them equal to each other, but the final answer I get is $\frac{1}{7}$.

Comment: what is $R$ in this question?

Comment: R is the midpoint of the parallelogram but it's not stated in the question, that's why I'm having trouble figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

Since $R$ is the midpoint of the diagonal $MP$, the length of $MP$ equals twice the length of $MR$. So, $12a+34=2(5(a+7))$. now solve this equation for $a$ and plug into your formula for $MR$. again as $R$ is the midpoint of $MP$, the length of $RP$ equals the length of $MR$

Comment: Thank you very much that makes more sense.